# Reverse CRC calculation

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, crc

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to reverse CRC calculation for serial communication between computer and device using VB.Net. I have few examples only.

Command (for reading the records from device):
ff ff ff ff ff 02 01 02 1a 03 aa aa

Responses with data:

02 01 0a 1a 3a 00 3b f6 ec 80 79 24 03 7f 7f
02 01 0a 1a 36 00 3c 13 a6 ad 69 24 03 02 02
02 01 0a 1a 12 00 13 6f ba af 69 24 03 df df
02 01 0a 1a 10 00 a7 05 43 2c e9 25 03 57 57

01 is device ID.
0a byte is length.
1a is command (probably).
Data is stored from byte 00 to byte 03.

Response when there is no data:
02 01 02 2a 03 87 87

I think that last two bytes are crc. Any help how to calculate them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your best bet for reverse engineering the checksum is to look at how much the checksum changes with just a single-bit change in the data. If there is only a minor change to the checksum you may be able to work backwards from there.

Comment: As the two bytes you think are the crc are always the same, it is only an 8-bit value, repeated. You could try this calculator https://www.ghsi.de/CRC/index.php?Polynom=110011011&Message=02+01+02+2a+03 wiith all the permutations of crc-8, inverted, reversed, etc. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check OR it might not be a crc, might be a checksum formed by adding, or by xoring the bytes together, or... whatever the protocol designer thought was a jolly good way of validating the message... Good luck!

Comment: Phylogenesis - I am not able to obtain sequential data, so ... Still, thank you.

Comment: barny - I will try, thank you.

Comment: What is the name/model of device?

Comment: @barny - There is only custom made sticker - Simons STAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the MAXIM CRC-8, which has these parameters:

```
width=8 poly=0x31 init=0x00 refin=true refout=true xorout=0x00 check=0xa1 name="CRC-8/MAXIM"
```

from the [RevEng catalog](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/all.htm). As noted in the comments, the 8-bit CRC is repeated in the message. (The five `0xff` bytes in your first example are not included in the CRC calculation.)

You can use [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate the code for that CRC.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot Mark! I'm diving in.

Comment: Once again - THANK YOU! I was able to calculate crc with your help.